# Bootstrap and Swiper carousel not working in Angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

So I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to make a carousel that has buttons and cursor grab. I've tried every fix I could find online but none would work. I even tried to copy paste a bootstrap carousel and the buttons didn't work.(P.S I've added bootstrap, Swiper and jquery into angular.json)
Here's the code I'm trying:

```
<body>
   <div id="app">
      
     <!-- Carousel slider -->
     <div class="carousel-slider" id="swiper">
       <div class="swiper swiper-initialized swiper-horizontal swiper-pointer-events">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="cursor: grab; transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(-4534.5px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="transform: translateX(1530%) scale(-0.8); z-index: 6; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -2; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/guardians-of-the-galaxy.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Guardians Of The Galaxy</h2>
                 <p>A group of intergalactic criminals must pull together to stop a fanatical warrior with plans to purge
                   the universe.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
 
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="transform: translateX(1240%) scale(-0.6); z-index: 7; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -1.66667; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/justice-league.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Justice League</h2>
                 <p>Determined to ensure Superman's ultimate sacrifice was not in vain, Bruce Wayne aligns forces with
                   Diana Prince with plans to recruit a team of metahumans to protect the world from an approaching
                   threat
                   of catastrophic proportions.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="transform: translateX(980%) scale(-0.4); z-index: 8; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -1.33333; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/spider-man.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Spider-Man: Far from Home</h2>
                 <p>Following the events of Avengers: Endgame (2019), Spider-Man must step up to take on new threats in a
                   world that has changed forever.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="3" style="transform: translateX(750%) scale(-0.2); z-index: 9; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/suicide-squad.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>The Suicide Squad</h2>
                 <p>Supervillains Harley Quinn, Bloodsport, Peacemaker and a collection of nutty cons at Belle Reve
                   prison
                   join the super-secret, super-shady Task Force X as they are dropped off at the remote, enemy-infused
                   island of Corto Maltese.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-active" data-swiper-slide-index="4" style="transform: translateX(550%) scale(0); z-index: 10; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -0.666667; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/thor-ragnarok.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Thor: Ragnarok</h2>
                 <p>Imprisoned on the planet Sakaar, Thor must race against time to return to Asgard and stop Ragnarök,
                   the
                   destruction of his world, at the hands of the powerful and ruthless villain Hela.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate-next" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="transform: translateX(380%) scale(0.2); z-index: 11; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <!-- elements with  "carousel-slider-animate-opacity" class will have animated opacity -->
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -0.333333; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/guardians-of-the-galaxy.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Guardians Of The Galaxy</h2>
                 <p>A group of intergalactic criminals must pull together to stop a fanatical warrior with plans to purge
                   the universe.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
 
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="transform: translateX(240%) scale(0.4); z-index: 12; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/justice-league.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Justice League</h2>
                 <p>Determined to ensure Superman's ultimate sacrifice was not in vain, Bruce Wayne aligns forces with
                   Diana Prince with plans to recruit a team of metahumans to protect the world from an approaching
                   threat
                   of catastrophic proportions.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="transform: translateX(130%) scale(0.6); z-index: 13; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0.333333; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/spider-man.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Spider-Man: Far from Home</h2>
                 <p>Following the events of Avengers: Endgame (2019), Spider-Man must step up to take on new threats in a
                   world that has changed forever.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="3" style="transform: translateX(50%) scale(0.8); z-index: 14; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0.666667; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/suicide-squad.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>The Suicide Squad</h2>
                 <p>Supervillains Harley Quinn, Bloodsport, Peacemaker and a collection of nutty cons at Belle Reve
                   prison
                   join the super-secret, super-shady Task Force X as they are dropped off at the remote, enemy-infused
                   island of Corto Maltese.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="4" style="transform: translateX(0%) scale(1); z-index: 15; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/thor-ragnarok.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Thor: Ragnarok</h2>
                 <p>Imprisoned on the planet Sakaar, Thor must race against time to return to Asgard and stop Ragnarök,
                   the
                   destruction of his world, at the hands of the powerful and ruthless villain Hela.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.8); z-index: 14; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <!-- elements with  "carousel-slider-animate-opacity" class will have animated opacity -->
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0.666667; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/guardians-of-the-galaxy.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Guardians Of The Galaxy</h2>
                 <p>A group of intergalactic criminals must pull together to stop a fanatical warrior with plans to purge
                   the universe.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
 
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="transform: translateX(-130%) scale(0.6); z-index: 13; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0.333333; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/justice-league.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Justice League</h2>
                 <p>Determined to ensure Superman's ultimate sacrifice was not in vain, Bruce Wayne aligns forces with
                   Diana Prince with plans to recruit a team of metahumans to protect the world from an approaching
                   threat
                   of catastrophic proportions.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="transform: translateX(-240%) scale(0.4); z-index: 12; opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/spider-man.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Spider-Man: Far from Home</h2>
                 <p>Following the events of Avengers: Endgame (2019), Spider-Man must step up to take on new threats in a
                   world that has changed forever.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="3" style="transform: translateX(-380%) scale(0.2); z-index: 11; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -0.333333; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/suicide-squad.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>The Suicide Squad</h2>
                 <p>Supervillains Harley Quinn, Bloodsport, Peacemaker and a collection of nutty cons at Belle Reve
                   prison
                   join the super-secret, super-shady Task Force X as they are dropped off at the remote, enemy-infused
                   island of Corto Maltese.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-active" data-swiper-slide-index="4" style="transform: translateX(-550%) scale(0); z-index: 10; opacity: 0; transition-duration: 0ms;">
             <div class="carousel-slider-animate-opacity" style="opacity: -0.666667; transition-duration: 0ms;">
               <img src="../../assets/images/thor-ragnarok.jpg" alt="">
               <div class="slide-content">
                 <h2>Thor: Ragnarok</h2>
                 <p>Imprisoned on the planet Sakaar, Thor must race against time to return to Asgard and stop Ragnarök,
                   the
                   destruction of his world, at the hands of the powerful and ruthless villain Hela.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div></div>
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
       <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
       <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-pagination-horizontal"><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active"></span></div>
     </div>
   
   </div>
   
 <!-- Cloudflare Pages Analytics -->
 <script defer="" src="https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js" data-cf-beacon="{&quot;token&quot;: &quot;07e9b2efafbd4b458690b79234a62148&quot;}"></script><!-- Cloudflare Pages Analytics -->
 <script src="//unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
   var swiper = new Swiper('.relatedproducts', {
            
            observer: true,
          observeParents: true,
          parallax:true,
        slidesPerView: 6,
        loop:true,
        autoplay: true,
        simulateTouch:true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.relatedproducts .swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.relatedproducts .swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
   </script>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: try to install angular library ng bootstrap that will help you.

Comment: that would work only with bootstrap carousel not the swiper one though, correct?

Comment: you can also install swiper component for it https://swiperjs.com/angular

Comment: that's the thing driving me crazy. I added everythinggg

Comment: please chk console or source code that jquery files link to your code or not .

Comment: so I've got two JS files linked in the head tag and they're not showing on debug. Any idea why?